# python ArgParse dependent arguments

Tags: python-2.7, argparse

I have a script `run.py` with some arguments and those are `-a,-b,-c,-x,-y,-z,-help`. **a,b,c are mutually exclusive** which I have done with

```
parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
```

Now my condition is,

for `run.py -a`, arguments **x, y and z all are mandatory**

for `run.py -b`, arguments **x and z are mandatory**

for `run.py -c`, arguments **y and z are mandatory**

So when I call the script `run.py -help` how can I manipulate this and shows a proper usage info?

Comment: You'll have to do the tests after parsing.  But what usage/help would explain these requirements to your users?

Comment: What's the action parameter for `-a`,`-b`,`-c`; `nargs`?  Maybe you could define `-a` to take 3 arguments.  If it is difficult to explain the inputs to your users, you should rethink the design.

Comment: @hpaulj thanks for your suggestion